# Try catch inside @Background function not working

Tags: android, background, android-annotations

Try Catch inside **@Background** function of [android annotations](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations) is crashing , my issue for this library can be found [issue#2035](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/2035)

How to solve this issue ?

**Note:** I want to use Try catch inside @Background function , my issue is not with string itself !!!

Comment: share error logcat

Answer (score 0):

Use `private String str = String.Empty;` instead of `private String str = null;`
This will then return a result of 0. Or you could also use `private String str = ""`

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Latest version of android annotation 4.3.1 solved this issue , i think it is fixed in latest version